# How to get numbers that haven't been selected

Tags: actionscript-3

How do I make a function returns a different number than the previous return, until it has returned all provided numbers.

I have this function (which returns a random number between max and min), and I call it every second:

```
private function randomNumber(maxNumber:int, minNumber:int = 0):int
    {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + maxNumber - minNumber) + minNumber);
    }
```

Let's say the 1st time it returns the number **2**. The 2nd time it has to return **1**, **3** or **4**, and lets say it gives back **4**. The 3rd time it has to return **1** or **3**, and lets say it gives back **1**. And in the end, it has nothing left to return except 1, and it returns it.

How do I make it so I only get a number once until I have been given all of them.
And when that occurs, I can reset the function so I can get again a random number from **1** to **4**. And repeat this indefinitely.

Comment: this doesn't look like java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it needs to remember which items have already been chosen, you'll need to store the selected numbers to check over them. So, I don't think this is going to be able to live in a self-contained function.

One solution would be to create an array with the values you want to select from, and also an array for the values that have been selected:

```
var nums:Array = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
var selected:Array = [];
```

Then, in a new function, you add the selected numbers to the **selected** array at the same time that you return them:

```
function getNextRandomNum() {

    do {
        // select a random item from the *nums* array
        var index = randomNumber(nums.length - 1);
        var num = nums[index];

    // loop until the number does not appear in the *selected* array
    } while (selected.indexOf(num) != -1)

    // add number to *selected* array
    selected.push(num);

    // reset *selected* array if it's the same length as the *nums* array
    if (selected.length == nums.length) {
        selected = [];
    }

    return num;

}
```